# jQuery loop through list-item and check child value

Tags: jquery, list, loops, each

I'm trying to loop through some list items and check for the value of the child field ".price".
This is the code I'm using.

```
var item = jQuery(".product_overview li")

jQuery(item).each(function() {
var itemPrice = jQuery(".product_overview li .price").html();
alert(itemPrice);  
});
```

But every loop gives me the value of the first child..

HTML

```
<ul class="product_overview">
<li><span class="price">20</span></li>
<li><span class="price">40</span></li>
<li><span class="price">60</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Side note: You don't need to construct another jQuery object from `item` since it already is one: `item.each(function() { ...`

Answer (score 4):

Try to use the `this` reference as the `context` to that selector,

```
jQuery(item).each(function() {
  var itemPrice = jQuery(".price",this).html();
  alert(itemPrice);  
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qHH7c/)

And as a special not you have missed one `s` in the class attribute of the UL element `clas="product_overview"`, try to correct that in your code.

Comment: Thanks, seems to work in my shortened democode. The actual goal is to append an extra class on the .price element, based on it's value.

If the value is "€0,00" then .class1, else .class2.
How can I do this? Thought I'd get there by alerting the values.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to:

```
var item = jQuery(".product_overview li")
jQuery(item).each(function() {
    var itemPrice = jQuery(this).find(".price").html();
    alert(itemPrice);  
});
```

Or just rewrite the whole thing to:

```
jQuery(".product_overview li .price").each(function () {
    console.log(jQuery(this).html());
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/aBb39/)**

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the prices in an Array,

```
var prices = $.map($('.product_overview li'), function(){
    return this.querySelector('.price').innerHTML;
});
```